# Split lists within DataFrames into multiple DataFrames

Tags: pandas, dataframe, split

I have this pandas DataFrame filled with lists filled with strings, that I wish to split into two frames:

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'A': {'a': ['NaN'],'b': ['1.11', '0.00']},
  'B': {'a': ['3.33', '0.22'],'b': ['NaN']},
  })
```

Desired output:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'A': {'a': ['NaN'],'b': ['1.11']},
  'B': {'a': ['3.33'],'b': ['NaN']},
  })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  'A': {'a': ['NaN'],'b': ['0.00']},
  'B': {'a': ['0.22'],'b': ['NaN']},
   })
```

I tried to use the apply function, which works for Series, and was wondering if there is an easy way to apply an operation that achieves this on the entire df.

Comment: Are there always either 1 or 2 items in each list?

Comment: yes, a mean and a standard deviation, or neither

Answer (score 4):

You can `stack` and `apply(pd.Series)`

```
s=df.stack().apply(pd.Series)
s[0].unstack()
Out[508]: 
      A     B
a   NaN  3.33
b  1.11   NaN
s[1].unstack()
Out[509]: 
      A     B
a   NaN  0.22
b  0.00   NaN
```

If you do need object for single cell

```
s[0].unstack().applymap(lambda x : [x])
Out[512]: 
        A       B
a   [NaN]  [3.33]
b  [1.11]   [NaN]
s[1].unstack().applymap(lambda x : [x])
Out[513]: 
        A       B
a   [nan]  [0.22]
b  [0.00]   [nan]
```